# wget .rar file from Github stopped working

Tags: github, wget

Since 2019 this wget command has worked fine:

```
wget -r -l7 --cut-dirs 6 -nH -N -A "*SDK_Ubuntu*.rar" --content-disposition -R "*return_to*" -R index.html -e robots=off https://github.com/signalogic/SigSRF_SDK/tree/master/rar_packages/
```

but today it doesn't. No error message is given, the only result is the index.html file being saved

2023-07-31 23:21:46 (3.91 MB/s) - 'index.html.tmp.tmp' saved [4720/4720]

I can't find any forum clues yet, but I'm suspecting Github recently changed something, possibly to do with serving wildcard requests. I've been trying slight mods to the wget command line, but no luck.